# [Oracle SQL]Selecting results based where results are found in another query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query for a search page based on user data; that is, users should only be able to search for other users whose results are similar to their own. Since each result is in its own row in its respective table, i'm using oracle's listagg() function to produce a list of user records.

Is there any way to search between two sets of records for similarities?
for example, something like:

```
select <data> from (select listagg(data, ', ')...where userid='<whatever>')
where <data> in (select listagg(data, ', ')...where userid='<whatever>')
```

Obviously this is pseudocode, but assume the '...' represent valid syntax that's been omitted for brevity's sake. Also in brevity's sake, i've only included one example; there are several fields that i would be filtering on, but i'm assuming they should all function more or less like this. Whenever I try something similar, what i'm finding is that the listagg function returns in the format of 'x, y, z', instead of 'x', 'y', 'z', which causes the query (using IN) to return no results, since there is no 'x, y, z' values.

Comment: Why use a listlagg when you can use a JOIN ON tablea.values = tableb.values

Comment: as far as i know(still learning sql, probably shouldn't actually be employed, but i am, so...), this couldn't be accomplished with a join. Can you point me in the direction of some documentation that might help me understand how that would work?

Comment: LISTAGG() can operate three different ways, as a single-set operator, a group-set operator, or an analytic function.  In order to answer this appropriately, we need more information about the details of your listagg() usage.

Comment: Ok, wait, i think I understand what you're suggesting now. as far as i know that wouldn't work here, because the user data and search data are stored in the same table. so it would be more like JOIN ON tablea.values = tablea.values,

Comment: I do JOINS on the same table all the time, depending on subfunctions that I have to build. IE: SUM, MAX, MIN etc. Why don't you post  sample of your table above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better approach

```
select yourFields
from yourTables
where userId in (
select userId
from wherever
where whatever makes them similar
)
```

Establishing similarity is probably the hard part.  Make sure you know the rules for that before you try to code them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is asking for...

```
SELECT a_concatenation_fxn_like_listagg(T1.FieldsOfInterest) as result
FROM theTables T1,
  (select FieldsOfInterest
   from theTables
   where userid = "user2"  //different user from T1
  ) as T2
WHERE
  T1.userid = "user1" 
   AND (
        T1.FieldOfinterest1 like '%'||T2.FieldOfinterest2||'%'
        OR
        T1.FieldOfInterest2 like '%'\\T2.FieldOfInterest2||'%'  //for string similarity
        OR
        ABS(T1.FieldOfInterest3 - T2.FieldOfInterest3) < tolerance //for numeric similarity
       )
```